# Is it possible to connect an iPhone to a bluetooth headset and also to wired headphones?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth, headphones

My wife and I often watch videos on the plane together, we used to use our iPad together with a headphone splitter so we could watch a movie together - but then we lost the splitter. Anyway, I'm thinking about getting bluetooth headphones for work and am wondering: Is it possible, for instance, to watch a video / movie on an iPhone (we each have an iPhone 6) or iPad with *both* a wired headphone plugged into the 1/8" headphone jack, and also have a second set connected via Bluetooth?

Comment: So you want to have sound played *at the same time* via Bluetooth *and* the headphone jack?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm interested in