# I have an iPhone 6. How can I use two Bluetooth audio devices and the 3.5mm audio jack together?

Tags: iphone, audio, music, bluetooth, headphones

Me and my friends want to listen to music together. Two of us have Bluetooth Headphones (Beats Solo2 Wireless, Beats Studio Wireless) and one has a wired headset. Is there any way to use all three of these together?

Comment: Has come up before (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244318/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-iphone-to-a-bluetooth-headset-and-also-to-wired-hea?rq=1), didn't get an answer there.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to each of the BT headphones in settings and then plugging in the wired one to see what happens?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101137/35933)

Answer (score 2):

As far as multiple pairs of Bluetooth headphones simultaneously, no, [not without additional hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164598/how-can-i-connect-multiple-wireless-headphones-to-the-same-iphone-6-at-the-same). While you can obviously pair your iPhone with multiple Bluetooth devices, it can only output audio to one Bluetooth device at a time due to limitations in the A2DP audio profile that is used to transmit audio to the Bluetooth device.

You also cannot output audio to both wired headphones and a Bluetooth audio device at the same time. They are separate options on the audio output menu in Control Center ("iPhone" is the output setting for wired headphones). This was determined through my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Get a mini-plug splitter and add a bluetooth transmitter or transmitter/splitter.

I have the [TaoTronics Wireless Portable Bluetooth Transmitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P24XKS8) and it works well.

I just ordered one of the latter ([TROND 2-in-1 Bluetooth V4.1 Transmitter Receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B4W40VC)) from Amazon and it has good reviews.

Comment: Can you update the links please?