# I have an iPhone xs max, can I use two bluetooth headphones

Tags: audio, headphones

My little brother and I want to watch Youtube without disturbing everyone. Is it possible to use two Bluetooth headphones at once?

Comment: The simplest way would be for one of you to wear the left earbud and the other the right side. Were you talking about something like that?

Comment: Does that help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250966/i-have-an-iphone-6-how-can-i-use-two-bluetooth-audio-devices-and-the-3-5mm-audi?rq=1 ?

Comment: What headphones do you have? See [AirPods/Beats](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210421), [bose](https://www.boseapac.com/en_in/support/article/using-music-share.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have iOS 13 and above and Apple airPods or Beats equipment. From [GadgetsNow](https://www.gadgetsnow.com/how-to/share-audio-with-two-bluetooth-headphones-using-this-trick-on-apple-iphone-and-ipad/articleshow/77442813.cms):

1. First up, head to the Bluetooth Settings on iPhone and pair both the headphones one-by-one.
2. Then, connect one of them and start playing any audio or video.
3. Now, open the control center
4. After this, tap on the Music option to see more options.
   Here, you’ll see the currently connected device is selected and playing the audio.
5. Look for Share Audio option and tap on it. The iPhone will automatically detect the compatible headphone and prompt to share the music with that.
6. Tap Share Audio button
7. Once connected, Apple gives the option to manually adjust the volume of individual devices.